# PYQT Loading Spinner to loop

Tags: python, animation, pyqt5

I am attempting to write a loading spinner using PYQT5, below is my attempt which seems to work ok. The issue is the spinner only does one animation then stops. I would like it to spin indefinitely until stopped. In my final code this function will be passed to a qtimer as I know runnning loops in the main GUI is a bad idea.

I followed the docs for
[https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractanimation.html#:~:text=If%20the%20animation%20is%20currently,and%20continue%20from%20the%20beginning](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractanimation.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20animation%20is%20currently,and%20continue%20from%20the%20beginning).

This quote is where I am going wrong I believe

If the animation is currently stopped or has already reached the end, calling start() will rewind the animation and start again from the beginning. When the animation reaches the end, the animation will either stop, or if the loop level is more than 1, it will rewind and continue from the beginning.

So question 1 is how to set the loop level? I tried

```
self._animation.loopCount(50)
```

and question 2 is have I implemented the following correctly so the animation isnt deleted.

QAbstractAnimation::start(QAbstractAnimation::DeletionPolicy policy = KeepWhenStopped)

```
 import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Spinner(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Spinner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            self,
            startValue=0.0,
            endValue=360.0,
            duration=3000,
            valueChanged=self.on_valueChanged
        )
        # Lets start
        if self._animation.state() != QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Running:
            self._animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeletionPolicy.KeepWhenStopped)


    def set_pixmap(self, pixmap):
        self._pixmap = pixmap
        self.setPixmap(self._pixmap)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QVariant)
    def on_valueChanged(self, value):
        t = QtGui.QTransform()
        t.rotate(value)
        print(t)
        self.setPixmap(self._pixmap.transformed(t))
        # Reset if at the end
        if value == 360.0:
            self._animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeletionPolicy.KeepWhenStopped) # Restart?


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        label = Spinner()
        label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.set_pixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("load.png"))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `loopCount()` is the *getter* function. Use `setLoopCount()`. Also, as the documentation shows, `start()` already assumes `KeepWhenStopped`, since it's the default argument value, so there's no point in specifying it.

Comment: @musicamante duh silly mistake thanks so much works great now